# Android Volley post request not working on click?

Tags: android, json, post, parameters, android-volley

Im creating an application where i can make reports and,on button click nothing happens,even the response does not come,toast not showing up. This volley post i have used it before and it is correct,another thing i should write is that i have to send the token for authorization.
this is my code:

```html
      //this is button click
      btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                volley_send();


                }

        });
        
       //-----------------------------------------------------
       
       //this is volley post
       
 private void volley_send(){


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "my_url",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        
                        // save_on_sharedPreference("email",email);
                      


                        if(!response.isEmpty()){
                            try {

                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                error = jsonObject.getBoolean("error");
                                String message = jsonObject.getString("message");

                                if(!error){

                                    //String token = jsonObject.getString("token");
                                    //JSONObject data = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");



                                   

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Raport_Cat_NoPhoto.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                }
                                else{
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }



                                // JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                System.out.println("JSONException :"+e.toString() );

                            }
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.err_connection),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                            //TODO
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.err_authentication),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                            //TODO
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.err_system),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                            //TODO
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"4",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.err_network),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                            //TODO
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"5",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.err_processing),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                }){


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Authorization","Bearer "+ApiKey);
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("category","cat_ankese");
                params.put("description",description.getText().toString());
                params.put("city",Qyteti);
                params.put("fshati",fshati.getText().toString());
                params.put("address",address.getText().toString());
                params.put("additional_information1",personidyshuar.getText().toString());
                params.put("name",emer.getText().toString());
                params.put("surname",mbiemer.getText().toString());
                params.put("telephone",telefon.getText().toString());
                params.put("email",email.getText().toString());
                params.put("info_latt",my_latitude);
                params.put("info_long",my_longitude);
                params.put("file[]",image123);
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

I don't know what it is wrong...

Comment: where is your volley_send() method? Please post complete code

Comment: im sorry because i edited it from my language and i forgot to change volley_dergo() to volley_send()

Comment: Did you add the permission for internet in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: And the url, are you using a variable on the url or you forgot to change the url to actual url and used "my_url"?

Comment: yes Joseph,i have added the internet permission and the url variable ,i erased it for confidentiality purposes. I have 3 other volley which works,one is post which sends two variables and two others methods in different activites which get data and they works ok. when i have to send a report via volley post ,they dont work. the method is the same,the only change is that in this case i have to include authentication header in this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sems like the problem was with the Authorization header,for any reason it requires only one parameter. Thank you all for replies!